# Selecting points which are not in polygons using GeoPandas

Tags: polygon, point, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have got two geodataframes: df1 which has got points as geometry type and has around 2.5 million rows, df2 has got polygons/multipolgyons as geometry type and has over 2.6 million rows. I want to make exclude those points from df1 which does not overlap/within/intersect with df2 polygons. I followed this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600811/using-geopandas-how-do-i-select-all-points-not-within-a-polygon and my code was like:

```
unioned_df2= unary_union(df1.geometry)
outside_df2 = df1[~df1.geometry.within(unioned_df2)]
```

The first statement took around 17 mins to execute. The program was stuck at the second statement. I let the program ran for about 12 hours but still it did not produce the result. How can I make it run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you found will work, but it is indeed very inefficient. The first statement creates one huge, super complex multipolygon from your big list of (simple) polygons. The second statement will compare each single point with this huge polygon to see if it is inside, which is very costly.

A more efficient way to do this is to use [geopandas.sindex.query](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query.html). Under the hood, it will first use a spatial index to search (very quickly) which points are within the minimum bounding box of which of your original, so relatively simple and small, polygons. Only for those point-polygon combinations it will go on to do the actual check if the point is actually intersecting with the (relatively simple) polygon. A similar number of intersections might have to be calculated if most points are near polygons, but it is a comparison of a point with a small simple polygon instead of with a huge super complex one, which is a lot faster.

I use the "intersects" predicate instead of "within" because you stated your needs like this: `which does not overlap/within/intersect with`. A point lying on a border of a polygon will be treated as "intersects", but won't be "within".

The call looks like this:

```
points_in_poly_idx = polys.sindex.query(points.geometry, predicate="intersects")[0]
```

Once you have a list of points that intersect, you can use pandas indexing to find the points that are not in this list:

```
points_outside_polys = points.loc[~points.index.isin(points_in_poly_idx)]
```

Full sample script:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely import box, Point

# Create some test data
polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        box(xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmin + 10, ymax=ymin + 10)
        for xmin in range(0, 100, 10)
        for ymin in range(0, 100, 10)
    ],
    crs=31370,
)
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[Point(50, 50), Point(55, 55), Point(200, 50)], crs=31370
)

# Find all intersections between points and polygons, using a spatial index for speed.
# The first result of `query` contains all integer indexes of all points where at least
# one intersection was found.
points_in_poly_idx = polys.sindex.query(points.geometry, predicate="intersects")[0]
# Exclude all points where an intersection was found.
points_outside_polys = points.loc[~points.index.isin(points_in_poly_idx)]

print(len(points_outside_polys))
# One point outside of the polygons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
polys.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor="blue", facecolor="none")
points.plot(ax=ax, color="red")
points_outside_polys.plot(ax=ax, color="green")
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using a spatial join. Points which are not within df2 will have na values, which can then be queried for.

```
points_outside_df2 = df1.sjoin(df2, how='left', predicate='within').query("index_right.isna()")
```

Also make sure you have geopandas 0.14+ installed. It has some optimizations which can help with the speed.